# Circular dependency detected while autoloading constant SpushHelper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In my Rails app I've several controllers and each of them should send push notifications to mobile devices. To achieve this I use gem 'RPush' and everything was ok when I've had init RPush, send notifications, etc methods inside each controller. But now I decided to refactor the whole code and create module where all these methods will be stored. Suggested I must include my module in `ApplicaitonController` to make it's methods visible inside all cotrollers and I did it. Now I faced a problem  `Circular dependency detected while autoloading constant SpushHelper`

[image]
[image]

My `ApplicationController` code:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
# Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
# For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
 protect_from_forgery with: :null_session
 include SPushHelper
 create_push_apps
end
```

`UsersController` code:

```
 class UsersController < ApplicationController
   before_action :authenticate_root!, only: [:index,:destroy]
   before_action :set_user, only: [:destroy] 

   def index
     @users = User.all
   end

   def destroy
    @user.destroy
    redirect_to users_url 
  end

  private

  def set_user
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:push_token, :uuid, :device_type)
  end
end
```

and my `SPushHelper` code:

```
 module SPushHelper

  ANDROID_KEY = "my_android_key_here"

  def create_push_apps
      #create android push app instance
      create_android_push_app
    ...
  end

  def create_android_push_app
    if not(defined? @android_app)   
     @android_app = Rpush::Gcm::App.find_by_name("android_app")
     if @android_app.nil?
       @android_app = Rpush::Gcm::App.new
       @android_app.name = "android_app"
       @android_app.auth_key = ANDROID_KEY  
       @android_app.connections = 1
       @android_app.save!
     end
    end
  end


def send_push_to_android(notification)
  get_users_tokens
  n_android = Rpush::Gcm::Notification.new
  n_android.app = Rpush::Gcm::App.find_by_name("android_app")
  n_android.registration_ids = @users_tokens 
  n_android.data = notification
  n_android.save!
end


def get_users_tokens
  if not(defined?(@users))
    @users = User.all
  else
    if @users.nil?
      @users = User.all
    end
end

if not(defined?(@users_tokens))
  @users_tokens = []
end

@users.each do |u|
    @users_tokens << u.push_token
  end  
 end
end
```

The error looks weird because I'm not using `SPushHelper` at all.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what is the name of the file your `SPushHelper` module is defined in? According to the error message it is trying to find `SpushHelper`, not `SPushHelper`, do you have another module named like this?

Comment: @BroiSatse thanks a lot! your comment is very helpful) P.S the name of the file was 'spush_helper.rb' now I changed module name inside this file from `SPushHelper` to `SpushHelper` and there is no more error with circular dependency :)